# Uncaught PHP Exception with doctrine2 insert date

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @param Request $request
 * @Route("/post", name="post")
 */
public function newAction(Request $request)
{
    // create a Post and give it some dummy data for this example
    $task = new AdsList();
    $task->setTitle('Write a blog post');
    $task->setpostedAt(new \DateTime('tomorrow'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)
        ->add('title', TextType::class)
        ->add('desc',TextType::class)
        ->add('postedAt', DateType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Create Post'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        // $form->getData() holds the submitted values
        $task = $form->getData();

        // save the task to the database
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($task);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('list');
    }


    return $this->render('postlist/post.html.twig', array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ));
}

}
```

i have this Controller that generates the following SQL on submit
INSERT INTO ads_list (title, desc, posted_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["r3123r2", "3er233r123r2", "2017-10-20"]

However MySQL says no ! :)
something is wrong ( this query looks good for me )

posted_at looks like

```
     /**
     * @ORM\column(type="date", name="posted_at", options={"default": 0})
     */
     protected $postedAt;
```

i get the following error

```
    Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException: "An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO ads_list (title, desc, posted_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?)' with params ["r3123r2", "3er233r123r2", "2017-10-20"]: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'desc, posted_at) VALUES ('r3123r2', '3er233r123r2', '2017-10-20')' at line 1" at /vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 94
```

any thoughts ?

Comment: Have you set `database_name` in you `parameters.yml` file?

Comment: yes i did :) i already have some working SQL :)

Comment: If you want to use reserved word, you can add it like this
`` arround it and it will not give any error.

Comment: better if i don't ( quotes scare me in SQL :D )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `desc` keyword you are using as a column name is a reserved word in MySQL, Doctrine does not quote identifiers automatically:

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

> Sometimes it is necessary to quote a column or table name because of reserved word conflicts. Doctrine does not quote identifiers automatically, because it leads to more problems than it would solve. Quoting tables and column names needs to be done explicitly using ticks in the definition.